# How to restore the window instead of open a new one if it has the same url(and still opened from the last one )?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, popup

I use the following class to pop up a specific window , but i wanna to ask how to use the same class ,if the user clicks a button and popup window with specific URL then click the button again with the same URL , i don't want to open a new window,just the same window if it still opened.

```
public static void Redirect(string url, string target, string windowFeatures)
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(target) ||

                target.Equals("_self", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) &&

                String.IsNullOrEmpty(windowFeatures))
            {
                context.Response.Redirect(url);
            }
            else
            {
                Page page = (Page)context.Handler;

                if (page == null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot redirect to new window outside Page context.");
                }

                url = page.ResolveClientUrl(url);
                string script;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(windowFeatures))
                {
                    script = @"window.open(""{0}"", ""{1}"", ""{2}"");";
                }
                else
                {
                    script = @"window.open(""{0}"", ""{1}"");";
                }
                script = String.Format(script, url, target, windowFeatures);
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, typeof(Page), "Redirect", script, true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second arguments of the `window.open` method is the name of the target window. If you use the same value for both calls, the second call will load its page into the previously opened window.

```
window.open('./a.html', 'popup', ...);
window.open('./b.html', 'popup', ...);
```

There will be only one window with the page `b.html` loaded.

Comment: `ResponseHelper.Redirect("https://aaa.aa", "_blank", "scrollbars = yes ,menubar=900,width=900,height=800,resizable=1");`

Comment: It opens a new window each time although the same `url`

Comment: Yes, `_blank` is a special name that always opens a new window. You need to use something else (which is not a value of any `name` attribute on the given page). That's why I typed `popup` instead.